# evitar descarga de Documentos

Tags: php, html

estoy montando una pagina para la empresa donde labora la cual tenga una recopilacion de los archivos que mandamos a nuetros clientes con el producto final, el problema viene cuando el cliente al hacer login tiene acceso tanto a la lectura como a la descarga de estos documentos.

mi pregunta es hay alguna manera de bloquear esta descarga?

Comment: cual es la diferencia de "leer" un archivo desde el browser (pensando en un PDF) y descargar el documento ? te lo pregunto, por que en realidad es lo mismo, para poder leerlo tendrá que descargarlo.

Comment: bueno en si la unica diferencia seria, que cuando la membresia del cliente termine el ya no tendria acceso al contenido de la pagina, y si puede descargarse los archivos ya no requerira tener acceso a la pagina para verlos

Comment: Claro en ese caso, la direccion del documento, pensando nuevamente en un PDF, no deberia ser una ruta absoluta sino una ruta relativa formada por parametros y que sea PHP en este caso el que lo traduzca, vea la seguridad de esta (ejemplo que tenga permiso para verlo o una sesion activa). Asi cuando el usuario vaya otra vez a esa ruta y no este logeado o no tenga permiso no mostrara el documento

Comment: Si puedes descargarse los archivos no importa que tenga una ruta formada por parametros una vez tenido el contenido no hay algo que se pueda hacer. Quizá proveer de esos materiales en PDF no sea la mejor opción para tu negocio.

Comment: entonses, conoces alguna otra opcion para hacerlo?

Comment: Pues la opción seria generar ese contenido en tu pagina con html, para que solo se muestre como menciona  jolsalazar, pero aun asi, el usuario podria copiar y pegar todo, o guardar la pagina web completa, lo que quedaria es hacerlo en flash o silverlight donde puedes restringir un poco mas la información

Comment: Puedes intentar imitar el lector de Scribd, hecho en HTML5, que te permite leer pero no descargar. Puedes copiar las páginas una por una, claro, pero si vamos a eso el usuario también puede anotar en un cuaderno el contenido del archivo y traspasarlo después a Word.